# Android Studio new project Eclipse style

Tags: android, ant, gradle, android-studio

How to set Android studio to open new Android project in "Eclipse style", and not gradle?
I wont to work with Android studio but that this project can be opened in Eclipse.

Comment: So what is the purpose of using Android Studio if you need "Eclipse style"?

Comment: The project structure, to use ant instead grandle

Comment: So in my opinion just stay with Eclipse or install IntelliJ Community Edition. Android Studio is based on it.

Comment: Can I install Ant on Android studio?

Comment: Android Studio will only support Gradle as a build system. Though we *may* support other build systems in the long term, Ant will not be supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use Android Studio if you want to stay with Ant (or even use the maven android plugin).

For now, Google maintains Eclipse and Android Studio.

If you want to benefit from the Android Studio improvements but stay with Ant, you should have a look at IntelliJ product : IDEA Community Edition.

Comment: What if two of my team want to use eclipse and the other two want to use studio? That's not possible and we need to make a decision on which we use?